# Is there a way to disable a warning in solidity code?

Tags: solidity, solc

I'm writing unit tests for some contracts and in some of the tests I'm generating a warning on purpose and `solc` will display this warning when compiling.

Is there a way to disable warnings in `solc` for the purpose of a test.

Something equivalent to MSVC++

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 44444)
// CODE
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Comment: I think you can select update version pragma compiler..remove constant and put view.0.4.18

Comment: Solc, from my knowledge, only compiles the code. It does not deal with address checksum.

Comment: It just seems like the address provided is not matching the checksum. The error tells you everything

Comment: address constant a = "0x0123456789abcDEF0123456789abCDef01234568"; try this..

Comment: According to the solc's command-line help - no. Maybe you can "suppress" it by replacing the `address` with a `uint256`, and then replacing every other occurrence of `a` with `address(a)`.

Comment: @goodvibration Yes, I know, it is bad on purpose, and I know how to fix this in particular. But the question is about how to disable an arbitrary warning for running automated tests.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend disabling warning for solidity code. They exist for a reason which you need to take in consideration.

Comment: Opening an issue on their repo and requesting this feature might be a good start, they're quite open and actually looking for user feedback extensively.

Comment: I've never reported it because in my opinion it is a bad feature for most users and likely it will be misused by bad library implementors.

Answer (score 1):

As of 24/05/2018, there is **no way to natively disable** the warnings the `solc` compiler emits. There is, **however**, a way to bypass those warnings by creating a wrapper.

Simply create a Node.JS application that internally uses the `solcjs` plugin, which is a port of `solc` into Node, to compile your local `.sol` smart contracts and filter the output of the plugin.

This is, indeed, a very unorthodox approach and **muting warnings should generally be avoided**.

Comment: It is a unit test, it fails and I detect that situation and report as such. I'd want to disable it only for that case for cosmetic reasons. I never reported it because I think it is a bad feature for most users.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [solidity-cli](https://github.com/pubkey/solidity-cli) which disables the warnings by default.

Comment: I want to disable a single warning, not all warnings.