# How to avoid block.timestamp warning?

Tags: timestamp

I am aware that miner can have influence on `block.timestamp`

My question is, how to avoid this warning?

[image]

Comment: I've asked that previously, but have no answers https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16307/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-warning-in-solidty-code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's currently a way to do this. (Either in Remix or in the Solidity code directly.)

The following open issues are relevant. You might want to follow them on GitHub directly:

- [#2675](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2675): Be able to disable all warnings for certain files
- [#2691](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691): Allow comments to ignore compiler warnings.