# How to disable 'Gas requirement not constant' warning in Solidity

Tags: solidity, gas-limit, compilation

I keep getting these warnings when compiling Solidity code:

`Gas requirement of function [...] unknown or not constant.`

I know that the gas requirement is not constant, and I've implemented a calculation to set an appropriate gas limit in my DApp's user interface.

Since I have addressed the issue, is there a way to disable this warning for a specific function or globally?

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible, you could try to disable the checkmarks in the 'analysis tab' related to Gas & Economy, otherwise share the code for us to inspect :-)

Comment: Just checking that you are asking about compilation outside of remix - correct?

Comment: Related: [How to avoid block.timestamp warning?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/how-to-avoid-block-timestamp-warning/29323#29323)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible.