# How to turn off specific warnings for the solidity compiler?

Tags: truffle, experimental-features

Whenever I use `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2` and `truffle`, I get the following warning in the terminal:

```
Warning: Experimental features are turned on. Do not use experimental features on live deployments.
```

Is there any way to turn it off, at least for development?

**Update Apr 2021**: this specific issue is no longer applicable to Solidity v0.8 and above, since the abi encoder v2 has been finalised. Changing the pragma to pragma solidity ^0.8.0 will make the warning go away.

Comment: Previously https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16307/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-warning-in-solidity-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry), there is a neat way to ignore Solidity compiler warnings, and that is to use the [`ignored_error_codes`](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/tree/master/config) config option:

```
# ignore solc warnings for missing license and exceeded contract size
# known error codes are: ["unreachable", "unused-return", "unused-param", "unused-var", "code-size", "shadowing", "func-mutability", "license", "pragma-solidity", "virtual-interfaces", "same-varname"]
# additional warnings can be added using their numeric error code: ["license", 1337]
ignored_error_codes = ["license", "code-size"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Even if "silencing warnings" has been debated for a long time (https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691 and https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2675), it is not yet possible to do it.

The explanation why not, is here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/security-considerations.html#recommendations